# Keeping Layers when Copy/Pasting in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers, copy-and-paste

I am new to inkscape but have some experience with Illustrator CS4.

I am working on a card game, and I have decided to create various layers to make it easier to order and select various elements.

However, when I tried to copy paste my card over, it pasted all the elements into the current layer.

Is there a feature that allows the pasting to be done in the respective layers?

I searched the web but only found information on the difference between copy, clone, and duplicates, as well as copying layers over from file to file.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to necro, but I believe duplicating (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) should make a copy and preserve the layers for each object--at least it does for me when I try it in Inkscape 1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I have found groups are more useful for organising content, rather than using layers in Inkscape. To group objects, select them and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Also the Objects panel is much more useful than the layers panel for seeing how everything is arranged/constructed. You can enable it by clicking *Object > Objects*.

Here's an example below. You can select a group, copy and paste, rename it, edit it, move it up and down the stack, etc.

[image]